# Kotlin - wrong val result in class with secondary constructor

Tags: kotlin

I have the following class in Kotlin:

```
open class Time {

    var hh: Int = 0
    var mm: Int = 0
    var ss: Int = 0

    constructor(hh: Int, mm: Int, ss: Int) {
        this.hh = hh
        this.mm = mm
        this.ss = ss
    }

    constructor(seconds: Int) {
        this.hh = seconds / 3600
        this.mm = (seconds % 3600) / 60
        this.ss = (seconds % 3600) % 60
    }

    val isValid = mm in 0..59 && ss in 0..59

    val toSeconds = hh * 3600 + mm * 60 + ss

    val toString = "$hh:$mm:$ss"

}
```

when i run the next unit test it fails:

```
assertFalse(Time(0, 59, 60).isValid)
```

but when i change to primary constructor the test returns the expected result:

```
open class Time(val hh: Int, val mm: Int, val ss: Int) {

    constructor(seconds: Int) : this(seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)

    val isValid = mm in 0..59 && ss in 0..59

    val toSeconds = hh * 3600 + mm * 60 + ss

    val toString = "$hh:$mm:$ss"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The problem:**

For you first `Time` class the test evaluates:

```
val isValid = 0 in 0..59 && 0 in 0..59
```

because `isValid` will be assigned before the constructor has been executed and `mm` and `ss` have not been assigned with the parameters which leaves them with the value `0`.

In your second version of the `Time` class, the constructor runs first and then

```
val isValid = 59 in 0..59 && 60 in 0..59
```

`isValid` will be assigned with the values you passed.

**Recommendations:**

Your second version is the way you would write it in Kotlin regarding the constructors. but if you want to make the first version work too, change `isValid` to a property without backing field.

```
val isValid get() = mm in 0..59 && ss in 0..59
```

This way it will be evaluated after `mm` and `ss` have been assigned. Using the getter would be also better if your properties would be mutable (`var`) in the second `Time` class. This way, when `mm` or `ss` changes, `isValid` will be reavealuated with the new values. The same applies for the `toSeconds` property.

`toString` should also be defined differently:

```
override fun toString() = "$hh:$mm:$ss"
```

because this is a convention which other classes expect, which enables something like:

```
println(Time(0, 59, 60).toStrting()) // explicit call
println(Time(0, 59, 60)) // toString() will be invoked implicitely
```

In the end, your class should look like this:

```
open class Time(var hh: Int, var mm: Int, var ss: Int) {

    constructor(seconds: Int) : this(
       seconds / 3600, 
       (seconds % 3600) / 60, 
       (seconds % 3600) % 60
    )

    val isValid get() = mm in 0..59 && ss in 0..59
    val toSeconds get() = hh * 3600 + mm * 60 + ss
    override fun toString() = "$hh:$mm:$ss"
}
```